# need to get the node value from the xml

Tags: javascript, xml, soap, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I use the following code for Getting the Id by using SOAP Services.I got the Xml Response for that it was working Fine.

```
    function guid(){

    var xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>" + 
        "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">" + 
        GenerateAuthenticationHeader() +
        "<soap:Body>" + 
        "<RetrieveMultiple xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices\">" + 
        "<query xmlns:q1=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2006/Query\" xsi:type=\"q1:QueryExpression\">" + 
        "<q1:EntityName>opportunity</q1:EntityName>" + 
        "<q1:ColumnSet xsi:type='q1:ColumnSet'>" + 
        "<q1:Attributes>" + 
        "<q1:Attribute>opportunityid</q1:Attribute>" +
        "</q1:Attributes>" + 
        "</q1:ColumnSet>" + 
        "<q1:Distinct>false</q1:Distinct>" + 
        "</query></RetrieveMultiple>" +
        "</soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";

        var xmlHttpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        xmlHttpRequest.Open("POST", "/mscrmservices/2007/CrmService.asmx", false);
       // xmlHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices/RetrieveMultiple");
        xmlHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
        xmlHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", xml.length);
        xmlHttpRequest.send(xml);

        var result = xmlHttpRequest.responseXML.xml;
        var doc = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument");
        doc.async = false;
        doc.load(result);


    }
```

**The Response is:**

[image]

I need to get the  from the result xml by using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Load the Xml in this way:

```
doc.loadXML(xmlHttpRequest.responseXML.text);
```